# difference between xmlhttprequest and $.ajax(), $.load

Tags: jquery

what is actually difference between

xmlhttprequest and $.ajax()

i want to know which is the lightest function from above to load data....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

XMLHttpRequest is the raw ajax request object. Working with this directly would be the 'lightest', but you're losing all the cross browser compatibility provided by the $.ajax() method in JQuery. If you want your code to work across all browsers, you must use $.ajax().

Answer (score 1):

$.ajax uses an XmlHttpRequest under the hood. See [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options)

You get the benefit of having it all encapsulated away by using $.ajax so I'd use that instead of writing all the cross-browser support yourself

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery's [`$.ajax`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax) is just a crossbrowser-compatible wrapper around `XMLHttpRequest.` You don't need to introduce countless nasty `if`/`try` blocks to get it to work in any webbrowser the world wide web is aware of. If you're using jQuery, you're supposed to use it (or one of the other [Ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) functions).